# variable width assignment from 2 wires in a new wire with bit masking [VERILOG]

Tags: verilog, selection, bit, masking

I'm trying to implement in hardware (using Verilog) the function described by this pseudo code:

```
if A then
      output [63:0] = b[63:56], c[X-1:0], b[Y-1:0]
else  output [63:0] = c[X-1:0], b[Y-1:0]
```

A is a boolean value, while output, b and c are 64 bits long.
X and Y change at runtime so they can't be Verilog variables.
The value of X changes with A:

```
if A then
      X = 56 - Y
else  X = 63 - Y
```

while Y is read from a 6 bit register so it can be any number from 0 to 63.

So for both cases of A all 64 bits of output will be assigned.
I know bit masking and mux selection with A is required but it is a bit complex and I can't quite get a clear picture on how to implement this in Verilog.

Comment: Why don't you use the concatenation operator { } for this?

Answer (score 0):

The runtime dependent bit selection can be implemented with **shift(<<)**, **variable bit selection(a[k+:8])**, a smartly designed **for loop(a[i] = condition ? b:c)** or a completely expressed **case**. And all of them should have similar synthesis result. Based on experience, the case implementation should have best area performance.

Here is an example (with testbench) for shift implementation:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps
module example(
    input A,
    input [5:0] Y,
    input [63:0] b, c,
    output [63:0] result
);

reg [63:0] o_a, o_abar;

assign result = A ? o_a : o_abar;
wire [5:0] X = A ? (56-Y) : (63-Y);

reg [63:0] c1_tmp, b1_tmp, mask;
always@(*)begin
    c1_tmp = (c << Y) & {8'd0, {56{1'b1}}};
    mask = (({64{1'b1}}>>X) << Y) | ({64{1'b1}} >> (64-Y));
    b1_tmp = mask & b;
    o_a = c1_tmp | b1_tmp;
end

reg [63:0] c2_tmp, b2_tmp;
always@(*)begin
    c2_tmp = c << Y;
    b2_tmp = b & ({64{1'b1}} >> Y);
    o_abar = c2_tmp | b2_tmp;
end
endmodule

module test;
    reg A;
    reg [5:0] Y;
    reg [63:0] b, c;
    wire [63:0] result;
    example ex(.A(A), .Y(Y), .b(b), .c(c), .result(result));
    initial begin
        A = 1;
        Y = 6;
        c = -1;
        b = 0;
        #10
        $display("%b", result);
        $finish;
    end
endmodule
```